# Regex in JS to find first characters of each word and cast to Uppercase

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for regular expression in JavaScript that will help me to return all first characters of each word in Uppercase:

"To do string" => "TDS"

Most important part is to return new string from old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy, with only two functions:

```
result = subject.replace(/\B[a-z]+\s*/g, "").toUpperCase();
```

In the [demo](http://regex101.com/r/lP4iZ6), look at the substitutions at the bottom. That's the effect of the regex replacement before the `toUpperCase()`

**How it Works**

- `\B` matches a position that is **not** a word boundary, in other words, a spot between two letters.
- `[a-z]+` matches as many letters as possible
- `\s*` matches optional spaces
- we replace all this with the empty string
- we convert to upper case

Comment: Added explanation, let me know if this works for you. :)

Comment: Yes it works perfectly. I also enjoy regex101 - it ll help me with others regex

Answer (score 3):

`"To do string".match(/\b(\w)/g).join('').toUpperCase();` will give you the desired result.

Comment: And +1 for a concise working answer, there's more chaining but I like it too. :)